# Visual studio code run another task in another terminal when launching the project with a background task

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, task

I have looked at the docs of how to setup [tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) in VS code. But its not clear on how to run a second task in another terminal while launching the project which already runs a task in background

I currently have a build task defined in [tasks.json](https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa/blob/master/.vscode/tasks.json#L4), which [runs on launching](https://github.com/asadsahi/AspNetCoreSpa/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json#L8) the project with F5

But I want to run another task which runs an npm script in opening another terminal. e.g

```
npm start
```

Opening in another terminal means, it can be killed seperately without affecting the original background task.